# Rotating a set of pictures aligned in multiple rows

Tags: graphics, subfloats, rotating

I made a figure that displays 2x3 images. However, I would like the whole figure, except the caption, to be rotated for 90 degrees. Here is the code that I tried to adjust by 'rotatebox' command:

```
\begin{figure}[]        
 \centering
 \rotatebox{90} {            
  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.34\textwidth]{a.pdf}}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{b.pdf}}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{c.pdf}}   
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{d.pdf}}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{e.pdf}}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{f.pdf}} 
} 
\caption{ myCaption    
    } 
\end{figure}
```

The above code displays pictures rotated, by aligned in only 1 column, one after another. I tried placing '\\' after c.pdf, but it reported error "Something is missing". What would be the way to obtain a 2x3 figure rotated for 90 degrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rotating three images at a time:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}[]
 \centering
 \rotatebox{90} {%
 \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.34\textwidth]{a.pdf}}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{b.pdf}}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{c.pdf}}
}%
\rotatebox{90} {%
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{d.pdf}}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{e.pdf}}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{f.pdf}}
}%
\caption{myCaption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: Instead of using `subfigure`, it is better to use `subfig` package.

Answer (score 3):

probably easiest is

```
\rotatebox{90}{\begin{tabular}{ll}
\includegraphics{}&\includegraphics{}\\
\includegraphics{}&\includegraphics{}\\
\includegraphics{}&\includegraphics{}\end{tabular}}

\caption{...}
```

Comment: In my setting, it would be '\begin{tabular}{lll}', with the adjustment in the alignment with '\includegraphics'. Then it works.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using the obsolete package `subfigure`, but `subfig` and the `\subfloat` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % [demo] is just for demo purposes
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rotatebox{90} {%
\begin{minipage}{12cm} % choose the size you prefer
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.34\textwidth]{a.pdf}}\,
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{b.pdf}}\,
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{c.pdf}}\\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{d.pdf}}\,
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{e.pdf}}\,
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{f.pdf}}
\end{minipage}}
\caption{myCaption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The problem was that `\rotatebox` doesn't allow line breaks in it; including a minipage solves the problem.